# search application being created with degraded partition

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search, index-reset

I have deleted and recreated a search application in sharepoint 2013 about 5 times now and every time it gets created with Searchable items All Errors and degraded partitions. What is going on??

Answer (score 0):

Helped me: run PowerShell script, then re-create *Search service application*:

```
psconfig.exe -cmd helpcollections -installall -cmd secureresources -cmd services -install -cmd installfeatures -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -wait
```

Or you can try index reset + full crawl of all my content sources, but this method did not help me, however, everyone recommends it.

[image]

Comment: reindex and crawl did not help me at all - I just ran your script but did not delete my search before, should I try to reindex my current or delete and recreate after running the script?

Comment: before run script.

Comment: can you tell me in steps? I have a bad search so i did 1. run script 2. delete search 3. recreate?

Comment: No, delete, run, create.

Comment: ok i already ran it, is it a problem if i delete and run again now?

Comment: and if i have 2 web front ends the script needs to run on both?

Comment: There should be no problems, especially the service is not working for you right now, do not forget that temporarily from 5-10 minutes, all web applications will go into reboot.

Comment: Better after working hours.

Comment: Do I need to run the script on both web front ends?

Comment: On both servers.

Comment: thank you - will try tonight: **delete from main WFE, run script on both WFEs (simultaneously), recreate on primary WFE ** correct?

Comment: did not manage to run script on secondary wfe - creating search now and hoping it works

Comment: still getting degraded partitions and searchable items all errors